# Hovering over links on other hovered link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, effect

I have a menu that's an `ul` list. Every button is a link with a `background-image` setting, and every item has `margin-top` set to 3. When you hover over the button the `margin-top` goes to 0 and the `background-image` changes to prevent flickering (You can see a small shadow on the bottom). Besides that I used `-webkit-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear` to make the animation smooth.

So far everything is great, but now I want to add 3 more links OVER the existing link. I've made it so the text is aligning ONLY on the top face of the 3D-like button, so the link has a `padding:18 0 0 1`, so that I could create a `div` that could cover only the top side of the cube. `<!--Just a head's up-->`

This is how it looks so far: http://jsfiddle.net/RWwXE/

I've sort of created the smaller menu (Which consists of HTML, CSS, PHP) with `span`, but I can't add `a` tag to them, because it all goes everywhere, and I can't track it down why does it happen.

I tried to stick the first links to the `li` elements using `li>a` in the css, so that it won't affect my links in the `span` section, but yeah, I'm a bit confused right now why when I make them as a link they jump around the place. Just started learning this, and got stuck, so sorry and would be glad if someone would explain if it's possible and what is the best solution for this?

Generally I want the big button to go up on hover, and the lower part to, let's say, change the font from gray to white, so basically it's 2 hover effects I suppose. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="categories.php">
            <div>Categories
                <div id="cat">
                    <span>HTML</span>
                    <span>CSS</span>
                    <span>PHP</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><div>Something</div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div>Else</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Menu */
.menu
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 103px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    /* Menu->Main Settings & Effects */
.menu li>a
{
    width: 198px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 3px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 18px 0 0 1px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/YBZHKcG.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    /* Menu->Front Face Text */
.menu li>a div
{
    width: 186px;
    height: 61px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font: 24px/61px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

    /* Menu->Effects */
.menu li>a:hover
{
    width: 198px;
    height: 103px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 18px 0 0 1px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/PVqqRqi.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: margin-top 0.1s linear;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu li>a.current
{
    width: 198px;
    height: 103px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 18px 0 0 1px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/PVqqRqi.png);
    cursor: default;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    /* Menu->Categories */
.menu #cat
{
    width: 187px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font: 17px/20px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.menu #cat span
{
    float: left;
    width: 62px;
    color: #555;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu #cat span:last-child
{
    float: left;
    width: 63px;
    color: #555;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML/CSS to the question.

Comment: Questions is so confuse... too much concrete text which doesn't provide anything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RWwXE/ here's the link of how it looks like. I want to hover on the HTML, CSS, PHP, and have it as 3 different links. So Categories -> categories.php for example, HTML -> HTML.php and so on. And have the hover effect on the HTML CSS and PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the effect you're looking for is [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/RWwXE/1/), but it's not entirely clear

If that is true, you just have to apply `:hover` CSS onto each of the spans in the list (HTML, CSS, and PHP). I did so by adding an individual class to each, given you mentioned having a different hover effect for each. If you want them all to have the same effect, then use the same class

```
.menu #cat .sHTML:hover {
    /* Effect on hover */
}
.menu #cat .sCSS:hover {
    /* Effect on hover */
}
.menu #cat .sPHP:hover {
    /* Effect on hover */
}
```

Side note, you really should use white space to make your CSS readable. The **only** reason you should remove that white space is if you need to make the file size lower when you're putting it into production

Also, CSS properties are inherited, so *you do not have to repeat styles* in a `a { ... }` in the `a:hover { ... }`. You only have to include the ones that need to be changed, I have done this in your jsFiddle for you

**Edit** based on comment below

If you're just looking to have them link to another page (within the categories link), you can use an inline `onclick="location.href='yourpage.php'"` for the container and use regular anchor tags for the list of links. This is because anchor tags should not be nested within each other

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/RWwXE/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah, but I probably should rephrase my title, I want each of the items to be a separate link. So that I have one big link "Categories" which goes to "categories.php", and inside of that link, 3 other links -> html.php, css.php, php.php. And thanks, I didn't know you could hover directly on elements too.

Comment: @Arno Updated my solution with a working demo of what you want

Comment: Yeah, it works now, thank you very much! It doesn't show the link in the status bar though, but as long as it works. From what I get you can't have a link over another one using `a` ?

Comment: @Arno You are correct, anchors cannot be nested within each other. There may be some type of CSS tricks to get around this as well, I'm not sure